# Supermicro x8SAX support

Tags: sas, supermicro

Does a  Supermicro x8SAX support SAS drives? I looked through the manual but am not seeing where this is mentioned.
I want to set up on board raid 1

Answer (score 0):

Did you not come across [this page](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/xeon3000/x58/x8sax.cfm) during your searches (the first result when you Google for the motherboard type)?

> Serial ATA
>
> ```
> 6 Serial ATA ports
> 6 SATA hard drives supported
> ```

No mention of SAS support - there doesn't appear to be a SAS controller onboard.

Just because there's no SAS support doesn't mean you can't have RAID - the ICH10R controller supports RAID. Just use SATA drives.

Comment: Ok, I did come across that page and I didn't see any mention of SAS so I just want to confirm. I am still learning and I want to confirm something here. By using a SAS controller I should be able to use the SATA ports on this board and do my raid 1 set up right? Please confirm

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The ICH10R SATA controller that is on board is already capable of RAID. You don't need a SAS controller. All you need are some SATA drives.

Comment: No problem. You might need to enable the RAID BIOS in the BIOS setup of your board. Check the manual for details of this.